# Emperor's signet ring is stolen, he embarks on adventure to get throne back

Tags: story-identification, novel

A *long* time ago (1995?) I read a sci-fi novel about an emperor who loses his signet ring (drugged or tricked, I think?) and by doing so loses the throne, and must embark on an extended journey to get the ring (and the throne) back.

The setting (if I recall) was somewhat steampunk and may have involved a multiplanetary empire.

Any idea what the book was?